# JAGS code for multilevel model with AR(1) autoregression - does this look okay?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, autoregressive, jags

There are a number of threads, blogs etc. discussing autoregressive models in JAGS, and but only a few that supply the code.

John Kruschke's [code](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/bayesian-estimation-of-trend-with-auto.html) for an autoregressive model with a sinusoidal component is:

```
model {
trend[1] <- beta0 + beta1 * x[1] + amp * cos( ( x[1] - thresh ) / wl )
for( i in 2 : Ndata ) {
  y[i] ~ dt( mu[i] , tau , nu )
  mu[i] <- trend[i] + ar1 * ( y[i-1] - trend[i-1] )
  trend[i] <- beta0 + beta1 * x[i] + amp * cos( ( x[i] - thresh ) / wl )
}
ar1 ~ dunif(-1.1,1.1) # or dunif(-0.01,0.01)
beta0 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1.0E-12 )
beta1 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1.0E-12 )
tau ~ dgamma( 0.001 , 0.001 )
amp ~ dunif(0,50)
thresh ~ dunif(-183,183)
nu <- nuMinusOne + 1
nuMinusOne ~ dexp(1/29)
}
```

I am looking to extend this code to the hierarchical/multilevel case. For instance, say we wanted the intercept, `beta0`, to vary by some group`id`. Would this be appropriate?

```
model {
trend[1] <- beta0[id[1]] + beta1 * x[1] + amp * cos( ( x[1] - thresh ) / wl )
for( i in 2 : Ndata ) {
  y[i] ~ dt( mu[i] , tau , nu )
  mu[i] <- trend[i] + ar1 * ( y[i-1] - trend[i-1] )
  trend[i] <- beta0[id[i]] + beta1 * x[i] + amp * cos( ( x[i] - thresh ) / wl )
}

for( j in 1:ID) { 
  beta0[j] ~ dnorm( ranInt , 1 / (sigmaID)^2 )
}
ar1 ~ dunif(-1.1,1.1) # or dunif(-0.01,0.01)
ranInt ~ dnorm( 0 , .001)
sigmaID ~ dunif( 0 , 1.0E-12 )
beta1 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1.0E-12 )
tau ~ dgamma( 0.001 , 0.001 )
amp ~ dunif(0,50)
thresh ~ dunif(-183,183)
nu <- nuMinusOne + 1
nuMinusOne ~ dexp(1/29)
}
```

This seems logical in the first instance to me, and the code does run, but I am not completely sure that it's correct.

The only other hierarchical examples I have found are [here](http://summerschool.sfs.ecnu.edu.cn/userfiles/1/files/ECNU3-JC.pdf) (search for the 'HAMD' example). Yet, this example appears to assume a wide data format (i.e. double indexing is used to specific, e.g., `y[i,s]`, with i the rows and columns the individuals).

Any help or pointers would be particularly helpful. Also, if this is better placed on Stack Overflow, let me know.

Comment: i am basically doing the same thing. it worked in openbugs But not with jags. The issue is redefiding. We can discuss more. If you want to see my code just search my post posted today.

Comment: I know this is old, but one issue is that autocorrelation will also be modeled in the shift from one `beta0` level to the next. I can think of many situations where there the autocorrelation would be lower for this shift than for any successive datapoints within a beta0 level. The magnitude of the problem scales with the ratio of the number of levels to data points (how large a proportion of the successions are made up of level changes).